# can we provide an oracle privilege to user which can alter only password of other user

Tags: oracle, privileges

I have created a procedure as shown below. This procedure is present in `schema1` and trying to modify the password of another schema/user let's say `schema2`.
To achieve this the user `schema1` must have altered user privilege but I cannot provide the `alter user` privilege to `schema1` due to some restrictions on the application level.
I tried to query using `ALTER SESSION` in the procedure but it is not working.
Can someone help me with the solution?

code:

```
Procedure p_demo(p_schema in varchar, p_pswd in varchar2)
is
begin
execute immediate 'alter session set current_schema ='||p_schema;
execute immediate 'alter user '||p_schema||' identified by '||p_pswd;
end;
```

Comment: You mean you like to prevent that a user changes his own password?

Comment: Can you do `grant alter user to schema2`? If "yes", then bear in mind, the user can modify the password also directly in SQL*Plus or similar tools and he can change also other user attributes, e.g. PROFILE. If "no" then it will be difficult because neither `schema1` nor `schema2` has required  `alter user` privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the `current_schema` has no impact on permissions or what user is currently logged in.  It merely changes how object name resolution works.  If you query an object `foo` when `current_schema` is set to `schema1`, Oracle looks in the `schema1` schema rather than in the current user's schema.  It does nothing to give you access to the `schema1.foo` table.

I'm not quite sure that I understand the goal.  If you are trying to ensure that only the `schema2` user can change the `schema2` user's password, you can define the procedure to use invoker's rights rather than definer's rights.

```
create or replace procedure change_my_password( p_username in varchar2, 
                                                p_password in varchar2 )
  authid current_user
is
begin
  execute immediate 'alter user '||p_username||' identified by '||p_password;
end;
/
```

If the goal is to have the procedure owned by `schema1` and to give users other than the `schema2` user permission to change `schema2`'s password (i.e. to allow an application user or a helpdesk user to reset the user's password), `schema1` would likely need to have the `alter user` permission.  Otherwise, it's probably not doable.

If you're really desperate, you could potentially use the undocumented (and I emphasize undocumented here, subject to change at any time, may have weird side effects, may tend to make Oracle Support unhappy) `dbms_sys_sql` package.  That's the package that APEX uses internally to run code as other users.  I don't imagine that a sane DBA would consider giving an application user `execute` access on that package rather than the much (much, much) safer `alter user` permission but if you're trying to work around some corporate policy and you're not much concerned about actual security...

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 users involved in this example:

- `scott`, who is trying to change someone else's password (that's your `schema1`)
- `mike`, whose password should be changed (your `schema2`)
- `mydba`, who is granted DBA role in my database (if you don't have such an user, `SYS` would do, but - you'd rather have your own "DBA" user, don't mess up with `SYS` if you don't have to)

Connected as `scott`, I can't modify `mike`'s password:

```
SQL> alter user mike identified by lion;
alter user mike identified by lion
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I'm going to connect as `mydba` and create a stored procedure which looks like yours:

```
SQL> connect mydba/mypwd@c11gt
Connected.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_demo (p_schema in varchar2, p_pswd in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    execute immediate 'alter user ' || p_schema || ' identified by ' || p_pswd;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_demo('mike', 'lion');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

OK; it works. I'll grant `execute` privilege on it to `scott`:

```
SQL> grant execute on p_demo to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Back to `scott`; see what he can do now:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@c11gt
Connected.

SQL> exec mydba.p_demo('mike', 'friday');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Do `mike`'s credentials work?

```
SQL> connect mike/friday@c11gt
Connected.

SQL>
```

Yes, everything's fine.

---

So: you don't have to grant `alter user` to `schema1`; let it use procedure owned by a privileged user who *can* change someone else's password.

Comment: "mydba, who is granted DBA privileges" is not precise. Most likely you granted DBA `ROLE` - but privileges granted by ROLE do not apply inside a PL/SQL procedure. So, apart from ROLE DBA your user `mydba` needs also `ALTER USER` privilege granted directly. However, according to the question user `schema1` (which would correspond to your `mydba`) will not get `alter user` privilege

Answer (score 0):

Cant we do as shown below: Tried doing this but it didn't work.
What i am trying to do is basically give alter user privileges to one role and assign that role to my oracle procedure.
Create role role_name;
GRANT ALTER USER TO role_name
grant all on role_name to procedure